# How to Remove a certain part of a string (if exists)?

Tags: mql4, mql5

I am trying to make the EA look for a certain value in a string and if that value exists in the string then remove it.

I tried doing it using the `StringReplace()` but i noticed it only returns the number of replacements and didnt actually returned the updated string:

```
string v5="- .82523";
          string temp2 =  v5;
          temp2= StringReplace(temp2," ","");
          Print(v5,temp2);
```

in the above code there is a white space between "**-**" and "**.82523**" and i  am trying to remove that white space.

so the string is       **- .82523**     and i am trying to get     **-.82523** , which function can be used for this ?

initially i thought i could do it by using the `StringReplace()` function , but seems like it only returns the Number of replacements that had happened and not the updated string.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the [`StringReplace()`](https://docs.mql4.com/strings/stringreplace) function incorrectly. Try the following code (from your example).

```
   string v5="- .82523";
   string temp2 =  v5;
   StringReplace(temp2," ","");
   Print("<",v5,"> <",temp2,">");
```